# Although already committed, can't view the private beta site

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

I had committed to the food and cooking website and got the email to use the private beta, but when I link there and re-login with my openid it says wait for public beta, i.e. it doesn't recognize me.  This is a duplicate account, because meta didn't recognize me either.

Answer (score 1):

We show your https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/148725/kevin-selker email address on the beta access list for Food and Cooking.

What is your main meta.stackoverflow.com account?